# Prepared Statement Function - Scope Error

Tags: php, mysql, function, prepared-statement

I am trying to write a function for a prepared statement but when I run the code it's giving me an error:

```
mysqli_stmt_store_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given
```

My function looks as follows:

```
function fn_preparedStatement($query, $types, $values){
    global $dbconnection;
    if (!$dbconnection) {
        die("Function wm_dynamicForm connection failed.</br>");
    }
    $db = mysqli_stmt_init($dbconnection);
    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($db, $query )) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($db, $types, ...$values);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($db)) {
            echo "Execute Error: " . mysqli_error($dbconnection);
        } 
    } else {
        echo "Prep Error: " . mysqli_error($dbconnection);
    }
}
```

Then in my code I have:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE First_Name = ?";
    $types = "s";
    $values = array("Mike");
    fn_preparedStatement($query, $types, $values);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($db); //im getting the error on this line - null
```

So im thinking my issue is a scope issue. I am not sure what to "return" out of my function to make this work. When i write the code inline it works fine. It's when I move the prepared statement to a function and replace the inline code with the function im now getting error. Can someone please tell me where im messing up? Thank you so much.

Comment: You may need to return the `$db`, or I'd suggest rethinking how you're creating your DB functions.

Comment: @user982853 I deleted my comment about that, I was momentarily confused. `$db` isn't a good variable to use when doing stuff like this and should be more like `$query` if anything. Your code is quite confusing.

Comment: Where does `$db` come from. You dont return the statement handle from the function so is it magic

Comment: `$db` isn't set in the global scope of the code, only in the function. I also don't think the third parameter of `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` can be an array.

Comment: @chris85 the code itself works fine when I type it inline. You can pass a an array as long as you "unpack" it in your code using (...). Again, my code works fine when i type it inline. I fails when i move it to a function. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the statement handle from the function

```
function fn_preparedStatement($query, $types, $values){
    global $dbconnection;
    if (!$dbconnection) {
        die("Function wm_dynamicForm connection failed.</br>");
    }
    $db = mysqli_stmt_init($dbconnection);
    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($db, $query )) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($db, $types, ...$values);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($db)) {
            echo "Execute Error: " . mysqli_error($dbconnection);
        } 
    } else {
        echo "Prep Error: " . mysqli_error($dbconnection);
    }

    // 
    return $db;
    //
}

// main line code
$query = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE First_Name = ?";
$types = "s";
$values = array("Mike");

// accept the stantement handle from the function
$db = fn_preparedStatement($query, $types, $values);

// so now you can use it
mysqli_stmt_store_result($db); //im getting the error on this line - null
```

Comment: That worked! I think ive been at my computer too long. I add return to my function but forgot to put the results into a var in my code. Thank you so much. Sometimes all it takes is a second set of eyes.